# Vaadin 14 fails to render but only when running from IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin

I am running Vaadin 14.8.1 and Spring Boot 2.6 and when I deploy the app to GCP it works absolutely fine however the same code fails to render properly when running from IntelliJ.

There is an error in the browser console which suggests there are duplicate js dependencies being loaded, however as this is a java app we don't specify any dependencies other that the java ones in the pom file. Any ideas how to resolve this?

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "vaadin-avatar" has already been used with this registry
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/@vaadin/vaadin-messages/node_modules/@vaadin/vaadin-avatar/src/vaadin-avatar.js:343:16)
    at Module.../node_modules/@vaadin/vaadin-messages/node_modules/@vaadin/vaadin-avatar/src/vaadin-avatar.js (http://localhost:8080/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-eb17c7fdd852fcb6b788.cache.js:3145:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-eb17c7fdd852fcb6b788.cache.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/@vaadin/vaadin-messages/src/vaadin-message-avatar.js:2:100)
    at Module.../node_modules/@vaadin/vaadin-messages/src/vaadin-message-avatar.js (http://localhost:8080/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-eb17c7fdd852fcb6b788.cache.js:3169:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-eb17c7fdd852fcb6b788.cache.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/@vaadin/vaadin-messages/src/vaadin-message.js:6:83)
    at Module.../node_modules/@vaadin/vaadin-messages/src/vaadin-message.js (http://localhost:8080/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-eb17c7fdd852fcb6b788.cache.js:3229:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/VAADIN/build/vaadin-bundle-eb17c7fdd852fcb6b788.cache.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../node_modules/@vaadin/vaadin-messages/src/vaadin-message-list.js:8:76)
```

Comment: Define GCP abbreviation.

Comment: How do you run it in intellij? What build tool are you using?

Comment: GCP = Google Cloud Platform. Building it with Maven and running it in IntelliJ via the run configuration pointing at the Spring Boot Application class, standard stuff

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project with mvn vaadin:dance and then run again?

Comment: I have deleted the node_modules directory, the package-lock, webpack.config, and webpack.generated files, run npm cache clean --force and rebuilt and redployed and I still get the same error. What's weird is I downgraded to 14.4.8 and it worked the first time but a second build resulted in the error again.